# ExtJS 5: How to setup model and store for 2 related comboboxes with nested JSON

Tags: extjs5

I have 2 comboboxes

```
 {
xtype:"combobox",
fieldLabel:"country",
displayField:"name",
valueField:"name"
},
{
xtype:"combobox",
fieldLabel:"State",
displayField:"name",
valueField:"name"
}
```

Nested JSON

```
    {
   name:"US",
   state:[
   {
      name:"California"
   },
   {
      name:"Texas"
    }],
   name:"Canada",
   state:[
   {
      name:"Ontario"
   },
   {
      name:"Quebec"
    }]
}
```

Now i want to show all the countries in first dropdown, and upon selecting a country, show the corresponding states in second dropdown. How do i setup models, stores and associations for the same. I am using 5.0.1 version

Comment: did you see this example from sencha http://dev.sencha.com/extjs/5.0.0/examples/kitchensink/#binding-combo-chaining ?